# Is there a method in Laravel PHPUnit to check if a Nova lens exists?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-nova

I'm attempting to write a test to confirm that a Nova Lens exists using PHPUnit. This will be used as the base case to build on whether certain users have access to that lens or not. Here is what I have currently:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Laravel\Nova\Nova;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class LotExpiryLensTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_lot_expiry_lens_exists()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(Nova::lensExists('LotExpiry'));
    }
}
```

When I run `./vendor/bin/phpunit --verbose --testdox tests`, I receive the following error:

```bash
Lot Expiry Lens (Tests\Unit\LotExpiryLens)
 ✘ A lot expiry lens exists  5 ms
   ┐
   ├ BadMethodCallException: Method lensExists does not exist.
   │
   ╵ /home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Nova.php:1261
   ╵ /home/vagrant/code/tests/Unit/LotExpiryLensTest.php:29
   ┴
```

I have also tried `resourceExists` with the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, as a user posted, you have to extend `Tests\TestCase`, not `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`, because the last one will NOT load Laravel at all, that is 100% unit test, you are doing a Feature Test. Second, you should not be testing that, as you are testing if Nova is doing what you want, and it will, because they have tested that... I still understand that you want to leave a check (test) so it passes or not, but as you saw, if you read the Nova documentation, there is no mention at all related to testing, so you should not be testing it

Comment: did you create this test class/file manually or using `php artisan make:test LotExpiryLensTest` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to extend TestCase from `Tests\TestCase` instead of `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`.

```php
//use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Tests\TestCase;
```